# OS X 10.6.4 defaulting to landscape printing

Tags: macos, printing

I somehow managed to change my printer default to landscape and 80% scale. This is the same for all printers. Is there any way to change the default back to portrait, 100%?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on Apple's discussion forums: http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=11321622

Comment: To quote the forum: The issue was resolved by removing the file `com.apple.printingPref.plist` from the User Library (`~/Library/Preferences`), logging out of the account and logging back in and immediately trying to print from the rogue application. Apparently the 10.6.3 update created a new Preference file that caused the first setting after installation to be captured as the default. This was solved with the help of AppleCare technicians who were experiencing a similar issue with some of their machines.

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks for adding the quote. I should have done that.

Answer (score 0):

In a print dialog, you have the option to select a preset (and to save the current settings as preset). Is a preset selected that is not the "Standard" preset? What happens when you select "Standard", are the settings back to normal?

Comment: No. I tried creating a new preset with "portrait" and "100%", but it still reverts to "landscape" and "80%".

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the printing system by ctrl + left clicking the box in system preferences.

[image: Reset Printing System]

Comment: That did not work. I just reset the printing system and reentered all of my printers (some not detected by Bonjour). Problem is still there.

Comment: You could also delete the preference files in ~/Library com.apple.PrintingPrefs.plist & com.apple.custompresets.forprinter."printername".plst, but it looks like you found another solution.